# How to change user domain name in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I deployed WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 and configured it with an external LDAP. But now I need to change the domain from `@carbon.super`.

Ex: [image]

Comment: Why we dont allow to change default tenant domain?? I am using WSO2 API manager 2.0. Is it possible in 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`carbon.super` is the super tenant's domain name. You can't change that. But you can create your own tenant and give your domain name like `api.com` or similar.

All WSO2 products support multitenancy, you can create new tenant, manage tenant through super tenant. Please have a look on [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Multitenancy)

Comment: Why we dont allow to change default tenant domain?? I am using WSO2 API manager 2.0. Is it possible in 2.0?